# What does $injector:modulerr mean?

Tags: angularjs

### Html Code

```js
var myApps = angular.module('myApps',[]);

myApps.controller('myAppController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApps">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="app/app.js"></script> -->
    
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="myAppController">
     <p>{{message}}</p>
 </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAp…Practice%2Fmodule%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A444%0A](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAp%E2%80%A6Practice%2Fmodule%2Fapp%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A444%0A)

Comment: is angular.min.js and app.js files loaded in network ?

Comment: The code in the example does not match the error message.  It says `Failed to instantiate module myAp…Practice/module/app/lib/angular.min.js:38:444
 due to:
{1}`.  The code in the example works fine. The question does not reproduce the problem.